# Why I can't auto post to twitter using codebird?

Tags: php, twitter, youtube, automation

I would like to reach this in steps:

-Upload a video to youtube using php and Youtube API v3

-After the video is uploaded, I wold like to auto post the video link and video title to the twitter, using codebird libery.

What I have at this time:

```
require_once ('codebird.php');
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey('YOURKEY', 'YOURSECRET'); // static, see README

$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken('YOURTOKEN', 'YOURTOKENSECRET');
// Call set_include_path() as needed to point to your client library.
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
session_start();
set_time_limit(0);
//More code for youtube uploading.............

// The point varibles:
htmlBody .= "<h3>Video Uploaded</h3><ul>";


    $htmlBody .= sprintf('<li>%s (%s)</li>',
        $status['snippet']['title'],
        $status['id']);
```

Post to twitter:

```
$params = array(
    'status' =>"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=".$status['id'], $status['snippet']['title'],
     );
     $reply = $cb->statuses_update($params);
```

And the erorr is what I get in the page:

> An client error occurred: The OAuth 2.0 access token has expired, and
>   a refresh token is not available. Refresh tokens are not returned for
>   responses that were auto-approved.

Comment: You *are* using your real tokens and keys and secrets and stuff, not `YOURTOKEN` and such, right? (Don't post them here, just yes or no.)

Comment: Ofcourse, but not seams secure share the real datas :)